# see commercials on TV or watch commercials on TV (could be any difference?)

Tags: phrase-meaning

> see commercials on TV or watch commercials on TV

Could be any difference between see commercials or watch commercials?

Comment: only the usual difference between "see" and  "watch", for which consult your favourite dictionary.

Comment: You see commercials on TV every day but you only watch those that interest you.

Comment: *See* is to *watch* as *hear* is to *listen*, so while there is some overlap, there can be and often is a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To "watch" something is *intentional*.
- To "see" something can be *incidental*.

Saying you "watch" something on TV idiomatically means that you customarily watch it. We would never say "I *see* [something] (on television)" to mean this.

The past tense is slightly different - we do something say we "*saw*" something on TV to mean we *watched* it, however it could suggest that it was incidental and we did not deliberately set out to watch it.